# xss with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, xss

i am using laravel 5.1

i use this code to save posts to db

```
 Auth::User()->posts()->save(Blog::create($request->all()));
```

and when i display post with this code some text and image i want to clean javascript and danger code !

```
<p>this is text</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="link" style="height:227px; width:342px" /></p>

<script>
alert("this is js");
</script>
```

{!! $post->content !!}

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXhIv.png)

when i use

```
{{ $post->content }}
```

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eZ3F.png)

i want display images and prevent danger code any solutions

Comment: what do you call danger code? if you allow the user to run js, than how the code will now what is bad and what is not?.. you need to read about xss and what blade {{ }} do to the code. than it will make more sense to you

Comment: oh I got you, you want only html but to disallow js? read about http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: i don't want any user to play on my site this is bad thing

Comment: so dont allow them to insert html if you want them to insert html, but not js than htmlpurifier.org

Comment: clam down, you want user to insert html, and to prevent them from inserting bad bad code, right? its very hard thing to do, so some guys do this for you and they give you this code for free forexample there is htmlpurifier package that remove bad code

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works on laravel 5.1 but on 5.0, you can use this :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class XSSProtection
{
/**
* The following method loops through all request input and strips out all tags from
* the request. This to ensure that users are unable to set ANY HTML within the form
* submissions, but also cleans up input.
*
* @param Request $request
* @param callable $next
* @return mixed
*/
public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    if (!in_array(strtolower($request->method()), ['put', 'post'])) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    $input = $request->all();

    array_walk_recursive($input, function(&$input) {
        $input = strip_tags($input);
    });

    $request->merge($input);

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

And add it in **Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'App\Http\Middleware\XSSProtection',
    ];
```

Thanks to kirkbushell : http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/laravel-5-xss-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{{ }}}` this will escape user input and you can use this to sensitize before store it in database so check these functions `HTML::entities();` or  `e()`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a wrong thing by allowing html code to go to our database.
That being said, make sure to sanitize input (make use of e($data['example'])) when saving content and output - by using {{ }} or {{{ }}}
As for the images, create a table that contains ONLY image name. Handle the rest by using your controller (image location and stuff).

Good idea is to create subdirectory named as ID of post and then to store image there.

For example post ID 7 will have dir -> images/7/imagename from database.